# Can I use an interface defined in IDL as a return type of a method of another IDL interface?

Tags: java, corba, idl

Let's say I create following IDL file:

```
module ProviderTest {
    interface Multiplier {
        long twice(in long number);
    };

    interface MultiplierProvider {
        Multiplier get();
    };
};
```

To be able later perform a call like that on the client side (in Java):

```
MultiplierProvider provider = /* obtain a stub form ORB */
Multiplier multiplier = provider.get();
int four = multiplier.twice(2);
```

Java IDL compiler generates code for that IDL without complains, but I'm having trouble writing an implementation for `MultiplierProvider` servant. It's `get()` method has a return type of `Multiplier`, which is a generated interface. In order to implement `MultiplierProvider`, I extend `MultiplierProviderPOA`, but I don't have a suitable implementation class for `Multiplier` so I cannot implement the `get()` method.

Normally (if Multiplier wasn't referenced from the MupltiplierProvider), on the server side I would extend `MultiplierPOA` (generated class) and then publish it via the Naming Service.
The thing is `MultiplierPOA` does not implement the `Multiplier` interface, so it's instances cannot be returned from `MultiplierProvider.get()`.

Am I missing some fundamental principle here, that you cannot do things like that with CORBA IDL (or maybe that Java's IDL support cannot handle such case)? If interfaces like that are possible to implement - how does the implementation work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I've found a solution that works for me. So, in order to get a reference of type `Multiplier`, that can be returned from the `MultiplierPorider.get()` method, one can create an instance of the class derived from `MultiplierPOA`, then register it with the ORB and at the same time get a stub from the ORB, which then can be returned from the `get()` method. Here's the code:

```
MultiplierImpl servant = new MultiplierImpl();
POA rootPOA = /* obtain a reference to the Root Object Adapter from the ORB */
/* get a reference of type Multiplier: 
   register the servant with POA and get a stub for it */
Multiplier multiplier = MultiplierHelper.narrow(rootPOA.servant_to_reference(servant));
/* construct the MultiplierProvider servant passing the stub to it */
MultiplierProviderImpl provider = new MultiplierProviderImpl(multiplier);
/* then register provider in Naming Context, so it can be obtained by the client using the name */
```

I've also checked, that after the servant is registered in that way, one can use following code to obtain the reference to the stub (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26445615/2519373)):

```
/* method _this() is defined in MultiplierPOA */
Multiplier stub = servant._this();
```

Although the implementation seems trivial, just to be clear, the MultiplierProviderImpl class could look like that:

```
public class MultiplierProviderImpl extends MultiplierProviderPOA {

    private final Multiplier multiplier;

    public MultiplierProviderImpl(Multiplier multiplier) {
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
    }

    @Override
    public Multiplier getMultiplier() {
        return multiplier;
    }
}
```

, and the MultiplierImpl could look like that:

```
public class MultiplierImpl extends MultiplierPOA {

    @Override
    public void twice(int number) {
        return number * 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. In C++ you would create a derived class from `MultiplierPOA` and create an instance of it. You would then use the `_this()` member function to return an object reference and possibly activate the servant on the default POA (if it had not been activated before).

In rough C++:

```
MyMultiplierPOA_ptr servant = new MyMultiplierPOA();
Multiplier_ptr object_ref = servant->_this(); // activate & create object reference
return object_ref;   // return to caller
```

I'm leaving out some arcane IDL to C++ mapping nonsense (such as `_duplicate` and `_var` stuff so I don't confuse you).

I realize you want a Java answer but maybe this will help. I assume the IDL to Java mapping provides a similar mechanism as `_this()`. You probably want to consult the [IDL to Java mapping document on the OMG website](http://www.omg.org/spec/I2JAV/1.3/PDF). From a brief glance it does look like the `_this()` method is supported there.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the specs, I somehow forgot that it exists and was mainly going through various tutorials. But in Java it seems it doesn't work exactly that way, calling `MultiplierPOA._this()` on the newly created instance throws an exception `org.omg.CORBA.BAD_INV_ORDER: The Servant has not been associated with an ORB instance`